# NVIDIA graphic card GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design NOT detected by Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 in VirtualBox.

Please Help with Getting my **NVIDIA graphic card and drivers** under the *Additional Drivers* tab.

I have an MSI GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design; I have tried to install nvidia driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31 on Ubuntu 18.04.2, but it failed. I have used:

```
pipe@alassane:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31.run
pipe@alassane:~/Downloads$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31.run
```

and got the following screenshot:

[image: installation error screenshot]

Also, when I open my Ubuntu Software and Updates, I do not see my NVIDIA graphic card. Here is what appears under the *Additional Drivers* tab:

[image: Ubuntu Software&Updates/Additional Drivers]

Here is my system info :

[image: NVIDIA Congtrol Panel/System Information]

Comment: You are running a Virtual Machine. It is unlikely you can install a proprietary driver there.

Answer (score 1):

You are running Ubuntu in VirtualBox. Instead of installing Nvidia drivers, enable 3D acceleration in the machine display properties and install Guest Additions from the machine menu.

Virtual machines can't use Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. In my Ubuntu settings, the **Graphics Controller** is set to **VMSVGA** (it is disabled) and the **Enable 3D Acceleration** checkbox is also disabled.  No option to enable them.

Comment: You need to shut down the machine before you can enable 3D.